# How does timeout work for the concurrent.futures threadpool executor map function?

Tags: python, concurrency, threadpool

I have a task that requires lots of requests. Some of the requests take too long so I want to time them out and ignore them. I am trying to do this with the timeout parameter to the threadpool executor map function. In order to figure this out I have been playing around with the concurrent.futures threadpool and I have code like this:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def sqr(argument: int):
    start = time.time()
    print(f"got argument {argument}")
    time.sleep(argument)
    print(f"Returning {argument} squared, took {time.time() - start} seconds.")
    return argument ** 2


def use_map_timeout(args):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = executor.map(sqr, args, timeout=3)
        print("starting comparison")
        for i, val in enumerate(args):
            res = next(result)
            if val**2 != res:
                raise RuntimeError(f"use map failed {i}, {val}, {res}")
    print("outside executor context")

def main():
    args = list(range(20))
    use_map_timeout(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**What I expect:** I expect

```
got argument 0
Returning 0 squared, took 6.151199340820312e-05 seconds.
got argument 1
got argument 2
got argument 3
got argument 4
got argument 5
got argument 6
got argument 7
got argument 8
got argument 9
got argument 10
got argument 11
got argument 12
starting comparison
Returning 1 squared, took 1.0005762577056885 seconds.
got argument 13
Returning 2 squared, took 2.002140522003174 seconds.
Timeout error
```

I would expect that this function runs until the sqr that sleeps for 3 seconds runs and times out. However it doesn't time out until the last time sqr is called.

**What I get**

```
got argument 0
Returning 0 squared, took 6.151199340820312e-05 seconds.
got argument 1
got argument 2
got argument 3
got argument 4
got argument 5
got argument 6
got argument 7
got argument 8
got argument 9
got argument 10
got argument 11
got argument 12
starting comparison
Returning 1 squared, took 1.0005762577056885 seconds.
got argument 13
Returning 2 squared, took 2.002140522003174 seconds.
got argument 14
Returning 3 squared, took 3.001537799835205 seconds.
Returning 4 squared, took 4.000811576843262 seconds.
Returning 5 squared, took 5.004898548126221 seconds.
Returning 6 squared, took 6.004707336425781 seconds.
Returning 7 squared, took 7.004103183746338 seconds.
Returning 8 squared, took 8.008176803588867 seconds.
Returning 9 squared, took 9.00804352760315 seconds.
Returning 10 squared, took 10.010106563568115 seconds.
Returning 11 squared, took 11.01113247871399 seconds.
Returning 12 squared, took 12.011764287948608 seconds.
Returning 13 squared, took 13.011804580688477 seconds.
Returning 14 squared, took 14.014004945755005 seconds.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/code/concurrency_play/threadpools.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/username/code/concurrency_play/threadpools.py", line 52, in main
    use_map_timeout_correct(args)
  File "/home/username/code/concurrency_play/threadpools.py", line 45, in use_map_timeout_correct
    res = next(result)
  File "/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 610, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result(end_time - time.monotonic())
  File "/home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 447, in result
    raise TimeoutError()
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
```

This seems like a very late timeout to me.
Why does this code not timeout when sqr(3) is called?